# CSS Grid Layout

Tags: css, grid, grid-layout

Есть сетка 5x5
Для заполнения строки с 1 по 5 элемент, нужно написать  grid-row: 1 / 6
Почему 1/6, а не 1/5, ведь элементов 5 ... или я что-то не понял[image: https://cssgridgarden.com/]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При размещении элемента мы ссылаемся на линию, а не на трек.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подробное руководство [здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout)